# Add the Object Being Called to Table

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append

I am creating a loop to generate a dataframe of analyst outlooks for certain stocks.

```
tick_list = list(df['tic'].unique())
print(tick_list)
```

Which generates:

> ['A', 'AAL', 'AAP', ..., 'YUM', 'ZBH', 'ZION']

From there I use my loop:

```
import yfinance as yf
t = list(df['tic'].unique())
a = []
for i in t:
    stock = yf.Ticker(i)
    a.append(stock.recommendations)
```

Which generates a list of dataframes for each object contained in the list. However, there is no indication of which ticker the table is for.

How can I include the object being called as a feature for each instance in the dataframe?

| Date | Firm | To Grade | From Grade | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-02-16 06:01:00 | Deutsche Bank | Buy |  | main |
| 2012-03-06 09:28:00 | Morgan Stanley | Overweight |  | init |
| 2012-04-19 08:35:00 | Stifel Nicolaus | Buy |  | main |
| 2012-05-15 06:14:00 | Morgan Stanley | Overweight |  | main |
| 2012-05-15 08:07:00 | Stifel Nicolaus | Buy |  | main |
| 2012-07-10 05:56:00 | ISI Group | Overweight |  | init |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to insert a new column into the recommendations dataframe containing the source symbol.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
df = pd.DataFrame({'tic': ['A', 'AAL', 'AAP', 'YUM', 'ZBH', 'ZION']})

t = list(df['tic'].unique())

a = []
for i in t:
    stock = yf.Ticker(i)
    tmp = stock.recommendations;
    tmp.insert(0, "Source", i); // Add new column to indicate source symbol
    a.append(tmp)

print(a)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your help!